# Making test cases for a contact form

Tags: selenium, junit, automated-tests

Okay I have a simple contact form with a project type, company name, phone, email, project name, project budget, description, attachment. I'm supposed write 5 tests on it. And I'm supposed to test functionality and what has the highest risk of failure.

When making test cases, should I make some tests fail? like 3 out 5 failed and 2 successes. Or does anyone have any examples of what should I be looking for?

Comment: Please ask the person that gave you the order to write tests.

Comment: This is not a programming question. You'd be better off asking this on sqa.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you have, the area of high risk in **bold** or required fields imho:

1. project type,
2. company name,
3. **phone**,
4. **email**,
5. project name,
6. project budget (digits or anything),
7. description,
8. **attachment**

So if I would write **5 test cases** I would outline like this:

**Test 1:** Positive, meaning all forms complete correctly user able to submit form,

**Test 2:** Required fields is not complete,

**Test 3:** Phone number is  not correct: 
a). digit wise
b). what if you provide characters instead of digits

**Test 4:** Email incorrect

**Test 5:** Attachment:
a). file as expected
b). file to large
c). no file